# Using shared memory in Windows 7 and Windows 8

Tags: fortran, shared-memory, pascal, intel-fortran

I got one application developed in Pascal and this application using some fortran files as library. In this Pascal application, coding are there to create shared memory and writing the values which is calculated in Fortran lib files. Actually the Lib files were in Visual fortran. So to work in windows 7 i converted this to Inter fortran and compiled it.
When i open application in windows7, and i m giving my input from the pascal application and it writes in shared memory ( im sure because i can see the calculated values which are get stored in shared memory).
But when i use this same application in Windows 8.1 Pro , the input values are not get write in shared memory. It always get the entered value as zero.

So, is there any difference in using shared memory in windows 7 and windows 8.1?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve